# MySQL adding new data by deleting old and keeping row count same

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a `test2` table, which gets created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test2(
name VARCHAR(20),
time datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Now I want to store only 5 rows in the table. So every time I add data it checks if row count = 5, then it deletes the oldest data and adds new data, else it just adds data. Here is the code:

```
IF(COUNT(name) FROM test2 >= "5") 
THEN 
(DELETE FROM test2 WHERE time = MIN(time) AND (INSERT INTO test2 (name) 
VALUE('icecream')));
ELSE 
(INSERT INTO test2(name) VALUE('icecream'))
END IF;
```

But this code formation shows 2 errors on the `IF` and `ELSE` statements. To reformat it for correct output.

Comment: And what does "user" have to do with this table structure?

Comment: Perfectly edited the table structure now for simplicity.

Comment: replace ` => 5` by  ` >= 5  `

Comment: are those single quotes around "name"? they should not be around column names

Comment: edited but IF ELSE still shows in red line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternatively you can remove row 4+ and add 5th. no procedure needed but it need two queries

```
DELETE FROM test2 WHERE id IN
(
  SELECT id FROM
  (
    SELECT id FROM test2 ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 4,999
  ) t
);
INSERT INTO test2 (`name`) VALUES ('icecream');
```

Comment: Hi I updated the question with your procedure answer. Could you please fix it?

Comment: @mimi just change `ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1` - works fine for me

Comment: I tried it still showing error. Could please post the complete coding for creating the procedure & how to access it in order to add data?

Comment: @mimi [use this code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fb82d0d788d18f7cc7771d46ac92db6b) then query database `CALL add_data('test')`

Comment: Thank you for your code, it just worked fine. I will suggest you to update your answer with your github code for better viewing of future readers.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine. Of course you need procedure to do it, you can't SELECT, DELETE and INSERT in same time

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `add_data`(IN data VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
  DECLARE c INT;
  SELECT COUNT(name) FROM test2 INTO c;
  IF(c >= 5) THEN 
    DELETE FROM test2 ORDER BY `time` ASC LIMIT 1;
    INSERT INTO test2 (`name`) VALUE(data);
  ELSE 
    INSERT INTO test2(`name`) VALUE(data);
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: There are 3 red mark with IF ELSE & END. This full Mysql code I need to execute with PHP.

Comment: @mimi you need to create mysql procedure, you can't use if else end if without procedure. you can't make delete, insert and select in one query